# finding the number of days in between first 2 date point

Tags: sql, sqlite

So the question seems to be quite difficult I wonder if I could get some advice from here. I am trying to solve this with SQLite 3. So I have a data format of this.

```
customer | purchase date
1        | date 1
1        | date 2
1        | date 3
2        | date 4
2        | date 5
2        | date 6
2        | date 7
```

number of times the customer repeats is random.

so I just want to find whether customer 1's 1st and 2nd purchase date are fallen in between a specific time period. repeat for other customers. only need to consider 1st and 2nd dates.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: How do you determine the 1st and second entries? Just by date? So customer #1 would be `date 1` to `date 2` and customer #2 would be `date 4` to `date 5`?

Comment: so in this situation i want to find the date difference between date 1 and 2 for customer #1 and then for customer #2 it would be date 4 and 5. I didnt write further but customer #3 would become date 8 and 9.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry I forgot to mention Im trying to solve this with sqlite.

Comment: Also please tell us which _version_ of SQLite you are using.  Analytic functions might be a necessity here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im using SQLite 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY "purchase date") rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    customer,
    CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN julianday("purchase date") END) -
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN julianday("purchase date") END) AS INTEGER) AS diff_in_days
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    customer;
```

The idea here is to aggregate by customer and then take the date difference between the second and first purchase.  `ROW_NUMBER` is used to find these first and second purchases, for each customer.

Comment: thanks! wow it is my first time seeing with clause. seems like i got a lot to research from. at least I got the right direction now.